# Error of send mail with laravel [Operation timed out #60]

Tags: laravel

Hi! I read other questions but I don't find my answer.
this error when I try send mail with laravel:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io
>   [Operation timed out #60]

and this my mail code:

```
class OrderShipped extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.ordersShipped');
    }

    public function ship(Request $request, $user_id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
        Mail::to($request->user())->send(new OrderShipped($user));
    }
}
```

and .env file :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=my username
MAIL_PASSWORD=my password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

thank for your help

Answer (score 3):

Every time you change the env file, You need to clear the config cache

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Yes! If you run php artisan cache:clear first, you may run into problems, especially if you were used a different ip address for your redis caching previously. Run php artisan config:cache first, like stated by Amitoz Deol

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer suggested by MailTrap's own website:

> What should I do if I get "Connection timed out" error when I try to send emails?
> Try to test your connection using telnet utility: telnet smtp.mailtrap.io 2525. You can find an example of the success telnet output in the Integrations section inside of any of your inboxes.

> If telnet doesn't work, in most cases it occurs because SMTP port is blocked by the firewall. Try to use another SMTP port (2525, 465 or 25).

> Check also if SMTP connection is not closed on idle timeout on the server side. If you open SMTP connection and doesn't close it after work, SMTP server will close it by idle timeout.

> If you still have the issue, please contact us at support@mailtrap.io and send us example of the email that you're trying to send to SMTP server.

Source: [MailTrap FAQ](https://help.mailtrap.io/article/23-connection-errors)